# wicket templates stored in database

Tags: java, wicket

Does someone know how to store Wicket html template files in database?

For example: if there is Wicket panel (let's say "MyPanel") which consist from two files: HTML template (markup file "MyPanel.html") nad Java code ("MyPanel.java").

Now I would like to store markup ("MyPanel.html") file in database and take it from database.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to implement a new `IResourceFinder` and add it when you are initializating the application like this:

getResourceSettings().getResourceFinders().add(new DatabaseResourceFinder());

Comment: will try it in next days, i will notify you about